# Data Visualization representation in Parallel Coordinates

Tags: d3.js

First of all I want to clarify this is not a programming question, more like a creative question for data visualization in D3. I am working on a videogame for high school students aim to improve decision-making skills. I decided to use D3 for data visualization of information as the best way for students to interpret and analyze data. For this scenario, students have a park and this park must have trees. However, trees have to be plant wisely based on factors such as income, popularity (to attract people), growth rate and many other conditions. To find the tree that will suffice any specific requirements, I present information of each tree through visualization. My best idea was to make a parallel coordinate graph in which students are able to filter data according to the set of conditions they are looking for and obtain the tree that will meet the requirements. Even though I think parallel coordinates are not a bad idea, I believe there is a better way to visualize this data. However, I haven’t found any other visualization able to filter data given a set of conditions. If you have any idea, I will highly appreciate it. This is the current model I am using for parallel coordinate graph: http://bl.ocks.org/jasondavies/1341281

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered small multiples with brushing? Students can select a subset in one small multiple and it will highlight the corresponding points in other charts in the small multiples.

I'm not sure if there are appropriate breakdowns in your data, but it might be worth a try. See this as an example: http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~jheer/files/zoo/ex/stats/splom.html